# __new__ method giving error object.__new__() takes exactly one argument (the type to instantiate)

Tags: python, python-3.x, magic-methods

why the following code is giving error?

```
class Foo:
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        print("Creating Instance")
        instance = super(Foo, cls).__new__(cls,*args, **kwargs)
        return instance

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

z= Foo(2,3)
```

it is giving the following error

```
TypeError: object.__new__() takes exactly one argument (the type to instantiate)
```

Comment: What makes you think this *shouldn't* generate an error?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
    instance = super(Foo, cls).__new__(cls,*args, **kwargs)
```

is correct. However, *you* are responsible for first removing arguments that your class introduces, so that when `object.__new__` is ultimately called, both `*args` and `**kwargs` are empty.

Your code should be something like

```
class Foo:
    def __new__(cls, a, b, *args, **kwargs):
        print("Creating Instance")
        instance = super(Foo, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        return instance

    def __init__(self, a, b, *args, **kwargs):
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.a = a
            self.b = b
```

This definition removes your new parameters `a` and `b` from `args` before passing it on to whoever is next on the MRO. Likewise for `__init__`.

Comment: It is a good suggestion, but still I cannot understand why if __new__ is not overridden everything works just fine: __new__ is supposed to get cls and constructor arguments. If __new__ is not overridden then it is object.__new__, right? And it gets all these additional parameters (does it?) and never complains, however explicit call super().__new__ fails.

Comment: Also, it is not always possible to remove "introduced arguments". E.g., class B is a child of some (yet unknown or prone to change) class A and we want just to do something in __new__, so it makes sense to call super().__new__ and give it all args we received. But if A does not override __new__ then it will fail. It looks kind of inconsistent. 

Possible practical solution is to check super().__new__  == object.__new__() and if True and send only cls argument. But it looks like a workaround.

Comment: Good questions. I suspect `type.__call__` does something different, depending on whether the class (or an ancestor) overrides `__new__`, or if ultimately `object.__new__` is being called immediately.

Comment: I had to remove `*args, **kwargs` from `super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)` to make it work

Comment: Yeah, I should clean up and expand this answer. In the mean time, see https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/ for advice on using `super` with `__init__`. (In short, avoid positional arguments, and use keyword arguments exclusively.)

Comment: (The problem is that you don't know which class `super()` will refer to. *Statically*, it's `object`, because `Foo` doesn't inherit from anything else. At *runtime*, it could be anything, because you don't necessarily know who or what will subclass `Foo`. If `object`, passing additional arguments is wrong. If some other class, *not* passing additional arguments may be wrong.)

Answer (score 16):

`object.__new__()` signature is `(*args, **kwargs)`, you may check this by using `inspect.signature` function.

But why then you have this error? **TLDR**: because you defined custom `__new__` method.

## Small research

All tests were done on Python 3.9.1.

---

Consider next class.

```py
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self): pass
```

Let's call `object.__new__()` on it:

```py
>>> object.__new__(MyClass, *range(10), **{f'a{i}': i for i in range(10)})
<__main__.MyClass object at 0x000001E7B15B3550>
```

No problems at all.
This class has only custom `__init__` and no custom `__new__`.
Now try to do the same call for your Foo:

```py
>>> object.__new__(Foo, *range(10), **{f'a{i}': i for i in range(10)})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: object.__new__() takes exactly one argument (the type to instantiate)
```

An exception about `object.__new__()`.
This class has both custom `__init__` and `__new__`.
You will see the same error when only custom `__new__` is defined:

```py
>>> class OnlyNew:
...     def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs): return super().__new__(cls)
>>> object.__new__(OnlyNew, *range(10), **{f'a{i}': i for i in range(10)})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: object.__new__() takes exactly one argument (the type to instantiate)
```

Let's check a class with no custom `__init__` and `__new__`.

```py
>>> class A: pass
>>> object.__new__(A, *range(10), **{f'a{i}': i for i in range(10)})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: A() takes no arguments
```

Absolutely different error.

---

Let's check how it works with inheritance.
Derive from A and define `__init__`.

```py
>>> class B(A):
...     def __init__(self): pass
>>> object.__new__(B, *range(10), **{f'a{i}': i for i in range(10)})
<__main__.B object at 0x000001E7B15D23A0>
```

Derive from MyClass and define nothing.

```py
>>> class MC(MyClass): pass
>>> object.__new__(MC, *range(10), **{f'a{i}': i for i in range(10)})
<__main__.MC object at 0x000001E7B15D2CA0>
```

Derive from MyClass and define `__new__`.

```py
>>> class Sub(MyClass):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs): return super().__new__(cls)
>>> object.__new__(Sub, *range(10), **{f'a{i}': i for i in range(10)})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: object.__new__() takes exactly one argument (the type to instantiate)
```

Derive from Foo and define nothing.

```py
>>> class F(Foo): pass
>>> object.__new__(F, *range(10), **{f'a{i}': i for i in range(10)})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: object.__new__() takes exactly one argument (the type to instantiate)
```

And now let's look on an absolutely exotic case:

```py
class Base:
    def __init__(self): pass
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs): return super().__new__(cls)


class Sub(Base):
    def __init__(self): pass
    __new__ = object.__new__


class Free:
    def __init__(self): pass
    __new__ = object.__new__
```

```py
>>> object.__new__(Free, *range(10), **{f'a{i}': i for i in range(10)})
<__main__.Free object at 0x000001E7B15C5A90>
>>> object.__new__(Sub, *range(10), **{f'a{i}': i for i in range(10)})
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: object.__new__() takes exactly one argument (the type to instantiate)
```

Both Sub and Free do not have a custom `__new__` method - in both classes `__new__` is `object.__new__()`.
But creating Sub raises an error while creating Free does not.
Seems like `object.__new__()` checks not `getattr(A_Class, '__new__', object.__new__) is object.__new__` but `all(getattr(cls, '__new__', object.__new__) is object.__new__ for cls in A_Class.mro())`.

---

## Conclusion

1. If a class has custom `__new__` in its [MRO](https://medium.com/@__hungrywolf/mro-in-python-3-e2bcd2bd6851), calling `object.__new__()` with >1 arguments raises TypeError.
2. If a class has only custom `__init__` and does not have custom `__new__` in its MRO, calling `object.__new__()` with >1 arguments creates a proper instance.
3. If a class does not have both custom `__init__` and `__new__` in its MRO, calling `object.__new__()` with >1 arguments raises TypeError.

Comment: Exotic case was great. It would be awesome if this was documented somewhere.

Answer (score 9):

In addition to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59218029/13944524) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65862579/13944524) answer, It's good to [have this response](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2008-February/076854.html) from Guido van Rossum here.

This addresses the behavior of `object.__new__` when overriding or not overriding `__new__` in subclasses and what happens to the extra arguments which passed that method.

> There's no point in calling
> `object.__new__()` with more than a class parameter, and any code that
> did so was just dumping those args into a black hole.
>
> The only time when it makes sense for `object.__new__()` to ignore extra
> arguments is when it's not being overridden, but `__init__` *is* being
> overridden -- then you have a completely default `__new__` and the
> checking of constructor arguments is relegated to `__init__`.
>
> The purpose of all this is to catch the error in a call like
> object(42) which (again) passes an argument that is not used. This is
> often a symptom of a bug in your program.

```
from inspect import signature

print(signature(object.__new__))
print('------------------------------')
print(signature(object.__init__))
print('------------------------------')
object(42)
```

output:

```
(*args, **kwargs)
------------------------------
(self, /, *args, **kwargs)
------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<>", line 7, in <module>
    object(42)
TypeError: object() takes no arguments
```

Comment: +1 This is the actual answer, imo. The accepted answer only explains how to avoid the bug that this is supposed to catch.

Answer (score 7):

This should work:

```
class Foo:
    def __new__(cls, a, b):
        print("Creating Instance")
        instance = super(Foo, cls).__new__(cls)
        return instance


    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

foo_1 = Foo(a=1, b=2)
foo_2 = Foo(a=1, b=3)
```

if you want to use Singleton design pattern, and create instance of class with params in constructor, this should work:

```
class FooSingleton:
    _instances = {}

    def __new__(cls, a, b):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            print('creating new FooSingleton instance')
            cls._instances[cls] = super(FooSingleton, cls).__new__(cls)
        else:
            print('using FooSingleton instance')
        return cls._instances[cls]

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

foo_s1 = FooSingleton(a=1, b=2)
foo_s2 = FooSingleton(a=1, b=3)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works, can you explain with details of the python logic here?

Answer (score 5):

You don't need to worry about passing the arguments up to the superclass. The arguments will also be passed into the `__init__` call.

```
class User(object):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        # do some logic with the initial parameters

        return super().__new__(cls)
```

Answer (score 3):

`object.__new__(cls)`, param is `cls`, not `(cls, *args, **kwargs)`